# How can I select this element in CSS?

Tags: css

How can I select `<button>` with the class `list-group-item` and status `disabled` in CSS ?

```
<button class="list-group-item" disabled>...</button>
<button class="list-group-item">...</button>
```

Something like ?
`button.list-group-item:disabled`

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are right. To select a disabled element, use the `disabled` selector:

```
:disabled {
    css declarations;
}
```